# Big O time complexity

Tags: time-complexity, big-o

I have a time complexity T(n) = 6n + xn and apparently the Big O complexity is (n^2) but I thought it would be (n). I would like to understand why it is (n^2).

Comment: What is size of "x", are you sure it is constant?

Comment: Does `x` scale with input?

Answer (score 0):

T(n)=O(g(n)) in computer science means this

[image]

So evidently your T(n) function belongs in set O(n^2)

But main question is that does your 'x' in T(n) depend on input of n?

If answer is yes, then it's obvious that T(n)=O(n) + xn belongs to set O(n^2)

If answer is no and x is just a constant factor, well then T(n) of course belongs **also** O(n^2) ( loose upper limit ). But tighter upper bound is T(n) belongs to O(n), because T(n) = O(n) + O(n) what is just O(n)

Because we are talking about upper limits ( big O notation ) it is correct to say that O(n) function belongs also in set O(n^2). If we are only interested that our algorithm does even in it's worst case perform at O(n^2) time.

Hope this helps